# FAST ESP 5.3 SP4 - Turkish tr-tr fails

Tags: c#, performance, fast-esp

Im using dotnet search api for [FAST ESP](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/capabilities/search/Pages/FAST-Search.aspx) 5.3. Everything works fine except for culture tr-tr i.e cultureid=1055.

Getting exception as "Error parsing information" on executing the below line

```
 qr = view.Search(query);
```

Can anybody please throw some light on this issue?

What & where to check whether my installed FAST ESP has turkish(tr-tr) support?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue as below through [MS support](http://support.microsoft.com/):

```
CultureInfo originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
qr = view.Search(query);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
```